# No translations for Hide/Unhide community buttons in the profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, russian-stackoverflow, hidden-communities

Can't find strings for translating text on <kbd>Hide</kbd>, <kbd>Unhide</kbd> buttons in transifex:

> [image: hide/unhide]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added localisation to both.

With you in the next build.

Comment: You mean added to Transifex, or directly into the code?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - in the code. Which when hits our build server goes to transifex.

Comment: Oh. So actual translation won't appear yet, until someone translates this in Transifex and it's approved?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yep, that's the process.

Answer (score 0):

Added strings successfully translated:

> [image: completed]

- [Hide](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/105402432?key=62a5e490880a92eef74f167d9dc6dca0)
- [Unhide](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/105402433?key=c41263e9868393a11717a8fd89de95f8)